# Wavelength of wavefunction graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, wavelength

So my professor loves to make like 10 exam questions where we interpret some graphs of quantum wave functions. Now I really do not understand how he reads off the wavelength for instance in these graphs. We first have a superlattice / multiwell.

[image]

Which is directly connected to the wave functions below.

[image]

Now the amount of zeros of the functions determines which state it is, so the one on top with no zeros is the ground state of an electron, and the above is the 4th excited state right? Now the issue is that he claims in the solution that the wavelength to the ground state is apparently

$\lambda/2 = 2.5nm \implies \lambda = 5nm$, but isn't it $\lambda = 3nm$? I mean reading from wave crest to next crest it obviously is roughly $3nm$. Or am I completely wrong now? Is it because the wave is decaying so we have to approximate that its longer than it seems than directly reading off or how? Also how do I read off the wavelength for the other wavefunction below? How do I do it as precise as possible, from which point should I start?

I have to be quite precise in these problems as a small mistake gives another alternative on the multiple choice, since I have to calculate an approximate energy for this by considering it as a particle in a box. ($E= \frac{4\pi^2\hbar^2}{2m_e\lambda^2}$)

Comment: I'm honestly not sure or else I'd help. Never seen this before. Might want to ask him or the TA

Answer (score 1):

Wavelengths are associated with periodic waves, where the distance between adjacent 'crests' is a constant. For decaying waves, the wavelength may be a function of $x$ or $t$, for instance if a decaying function may 'move' faster along $x$ causing the wavelength to increase as the amplitude is decreasing (while the frequency is kept constant). This is another feature of wavelengths - movement. Thus, associating *wavelengths* with stationary *wavefunctions* may cause confusion.

You are right! Wavelength is the distance in which the wave completes one oscillation, and for waves with constant wavelength, this is equal to the distance between two crests or troughs. This quantity may be difficult to define for wavefunctions with nodes. I scaled the image and found that the average distance between the crests and troughs for the ground state is about $\lambda \approx 2.9nm$, which is much closer to your answer.

Another interpretation of wavelengths from wavefunctions are the corresponding energies of photons associated with the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian. If you have these values available, simply use the relation $E = h\nu = h\dfrac{c}{\lambda}$. However, do note that it is customary to report these values in inverse-length, most commonly $cm^{-1}$, units, as wavenumber $\bar{\text{v}} = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

$$
\bar{\text{v}} = \dfrac{E}{hc}
$$